# Cannot call stored procedure from code which works on direct call to database

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, informix

I connected to the Informix server using RazorSQL, created a stored procedure and tested it, getting the expected answer, so the procedure exists in the database in some form.

I then run the following code:

```
If ConnectToInformix() Then
    Dim cmd As New IfxCommand("dc_routeHasOutstandingQuantity", conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New IfxParameter("WorksOrder", wo_num))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New IfxParameter("CompNo", IBM.Data.Informix.IfxType.SmallInt)).Value = CType(compNo, Int16)
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

For completeness' sake, here is the ConnectToInformix function.

```
Private Function ConnectToInformix() As Boolean
    Try
        If conn Is Nothing Then
            conn = New IfxConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
        End If
        If conn.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If
        Return True
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        conn.Dispose()
        conn = Nothing
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The ConnectToInformix function works fine for every other Informix connection made by this program, but this is the first Informix stored procedure being used, so maybe there's some special magic I have to work on the connection...

Anyway, when I try to call the stored procedure on the `rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader` line I get the following error:

```
ERROR [HY000] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]Cannot read system catalog (sysprocedures).
```

This error does not occur when calling the stored procedure from a live SQL connection.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does informix have a `sysprocedures` catalog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I'd check is you’re user has permissions to the database, and to that stored procedure.

Comment: Oh *damn*. These programs I've been working on have all been created with a primary check of their user credentials to an SQL Server instance, before getting automatic access to a specific Informix username/password. *This* program just logs them straight into the Informix database with their usual login. Well, I look like an idiot for not checking that first, but that looks like the root of the problem.